# requests.get raises IncompleteRead Error with redirecting url

Tags: python-3.x

So, i have an url that redirects you. it works with webbrowser.open nicely but requests raises incompleteread error. I'm using python 3.8 on Windows 10

```
Id='16977332'
D = f'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/elink.fcgi?dbfrom=pubmed&id={Id}&cmd=prlinks&retmode=ref'
re_dlink = requests.get(D)
```

run this, and...

```
    raise httplib.IncompleteRead(line)
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)
```

UPDATE:

I tried this and it returned 400, bad request. Maybe the URL processed before it gets the target URL.

```
import http.client
http.client.HTTPConnection._http_vsn = 10
```

I can get redirected url with selenium but i don't want to use external exe. With that, I decided to choose the long way so i removed retmode=ref from url. [Here, you can find info about these urls under the Elink header](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/)

Answer (score 0):

You've written the `Id` in `str` format. Write that in `int` like this

```
Id = 16977332
```

And it's done.